# Modifying a style of bib

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I need to modify this style s.t. the call of a reference on text appear with braquets instead of parenteses. Indeed, I'd like to get **bf** at the principal title of reference at bibliography. Could someone help me?

https://github.com/manoelcampos/ft-unb-latex-template/blob/master/abnt-num.bst

```
 \documentclass[ english,brazil]{abntbibufjf}
    \usepackage{lmodern}                        
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{lastpage}           
    \usepackage{indentfirst}        
    \usepackage{color}          
    \usepackage{graphicx}           
    \usepackage{microtype} 
    \usepackage[square]{natbib}

    \titulo{A definir} 
    \subtitulo{a definir}  
    ...


    \begin{document}
    ...
    \begin{agradecimentos}
    Agrade\c{c}o aos ... 
    \end{agradecimentos}

    \begin{epigrafe} 
        ''E tudo o que fizerdes, seja em palavra, seja em ação, fazei-o em nome
do Senhor Jesus, dando por ele graças a Deus Pai.'' Colossenses 3:17. 
    \end{epigrafe}

    ...
    \chapter{NOME DO CAP\'ITULO}
    Segundo \citep{chapiro2016numerical}...

    ...

  ...

   ...

   ...

    \section{ELEMENTOS P\'OS-TEXTUAIS}
...

    \postextual 
    \bibliographystyle{abnt-num}
    \bibliography{ref.bib}
   ...
```

---

```
%% abntbibufjf.cls, v-2 JB-LP-LA
%% 
  %% Copyright 2014 Jos\'e Barbosa (ICE-UFJF), Larissa Pinheiro (CDC-UFJF), L\'ivia Alonso (CDC-UFJF).
  %
  % This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
  % conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either 
  % version 1.3 of this license or (at your option) any later 
  % version. The latest version of this license is in
  %       http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
  % and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
  % version 2005/12/01 or later.
  %
  % This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
  % 
  % The Current Maintainer of this work is Jos\'e Barbosa (ICE-UFJF).
  %
  % This work consists of the files abntbibufjf.cls.
% 
% 
%  
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%Os acentos foram desprezados neste arquivo.
%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{abntbibufjf}[2019/09/05 v 2]


\RequirePackage{ifthen}


\DeclareOption*{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{memoir}%
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------


\newcommand{\ifnotempty}[2]{\ifthenelse{\not\equal{#1}{}}{#2}{}} 

\RequirePackage[hypertexnames=false, hidelinks]{hyperref}    
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\\{, }\def\and{; }}

\RequirePackage{bookmark}               

\RequirePackage[brazil]{babel}

\RequirePackage{enumitem}

\RequirePackage{calc} 

%
\newcommand{\folhaderostoname}{Folha de rosto}
\newcommand{\epigraphname}{Ep\'igrafe}
\newcommand{\dedicatorianame}{Dedicat\'oria}
\newcommand{\agradecimentosname}{\bfseries AGRADECIMENTOS}
\newcommand{\anexoname}{\bfseries ANEXO}
\newcommand{\anexosname}{Anexos}
\newcommand{\apendicename}{\bfseries AP\^ENDICE}
\newcommand{\apendicesname}{Ap\^endices}
\newcommand{\orientadorname}{Orientador:}
\newcommand{\coorientadorname}{Coorientador:}
\newcommand{\folhadeaprovacaoname}{\bfseries FOLHA DE APROVA\c{C}\~AO}
\newcommand{\resumoname}{RESUMO} 
\newcommand{\listadesiglasname}{\bfseries LISTA DE ABREVIATURAS E SIGLAS}
\newcommand{\listadesimbolosname}{\bfseries LISTA DE S\'IMBOLOS}
\newcommand{\fontename}{Fonte}
\newcommand{\notaname}{Nota}
%% --
\addto\captionsbrazil{% 
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\bfseries SUM\'ARIO} %%
  \renewcommand{\bibname}{\bfseries REFER\^ENCIAS}
  \renewcommand{\indexname}{\bfseries \'INDICE}
  \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\bfseries LISTA DE ILUSTRA\c{C}\~{O}ES}
  \renewcommand{\listtablename}{\bfseries LISTA DE TABELAS}
}

%% --
\def\au@classname{abntbibufjf} 


\newif\if@eu@ilhookcalled\@eu@ilhookcalledfalse
\newif\if@eu@hasil\@eu@hasilfalse

\def\au@eu@ilaux{\global\@eu@hasiltrue}
\def\au@eu@ilhook{%
  \if@eu@ilhookcalled\else
    \global\@eu@ilhookcalledtrue
    \global\@eu@hasiltrue
    \immediate\write\@auxout{%
      \string\au@eu@ilaux{}^^J
    }%
    \typeout{* \au@classname: Il }%
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\auaddilcmd}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\au@temp#1
  \expandafter\gdef\expandafter#1\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\au@eu@ilhook\au@temp}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\auaddilenv}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \expandafter\auaddilcmd\expandafter{\csname#1\endcsname}%
  \endgroup
}
\AtBeginDocument{\auaddilenv{figure}}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setlrmarginsandblock{3cm}{2cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{2cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

\OnehalfSpacing
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\afterchapskip}{\onelineskip}} 

%% ---

\setlength{\parindent}{1.3cm}

\setlength{\parskip}{4pt}

\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{0pt} 

%% ---

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\chapterfont}{\rmfamily} 
\newcommand{\chapterfontsize}{\normalsize}

\newcommand{\partfont}{\chapterfont}
\newcommand{\partfontsize}{\chapterfontsize}

\newcommand{\sectionfont}{\chapterfont}
\newcommand{\sectionfontsize}{\normalsize}

\newcommand{\subsectionfont}{\sectionfont}
\newcommand{\subsectionfontsize}{\normalsize}

\newcommand{\subsubsectionfont}{\subsectionfont}
\newcommand{\subsubsectionfontsize}{\normalsize}

\newcommand{\subsubsubsectionfont}{\subsectionfont}
\newcommand{\subsubsubsectionfontsize}{\normalsize}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcounter{bookmarkcounter} 
\setcounter{bookmarkcounter}{0}
\newcommand{\AUbookmarkthis}[1]{%
  \addtocounter{bookmarkcounter}{1}%
  \phantomsection\pdfbookmark[0]{#1}{chapterb\arabic{bookmarkcounter}}
}

\newcommand{\pretextualchapter}[1]{%
  \addtocounter{bookmarkcounter}{1}%
  \AUbookmarkthis{#1}%
  \chapter*[#1]{#1}%
  }
\provideboolean{apendiceousecao}      
\setboolean{apendiceousecao}{false}


% ------------------------------------------------------------------------


\renewcommand{\foottextfont}{\small}
\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{1.2em}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{0em}
\footmarkstyle{\footnotesize{\textsuperscript{#1}}\hfill}

  \counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
  \counterwithout{table}{chapter}
%%%}
%------------------------------------

\captiondelim{~\textendash ~} 
\captionnamefont{\normalsize}
\captiontitlefont{\normalsize}
\indentcaption{0pt} 
\captionstyle[\centering]{\centerlastline} 
\newcommand{\larguratexto}{\changecaptionwidth \captionwidth} 

\newcommand{\configureseparator}{\captiondelim{: }}

\newcommand{\fonte}[2][\fontename]{%
  \M@gettitle{#2}%
  \memlegendinfo{#2}%
  \par
  \begingroup
  \captionstyle{\raggedright}{\raggedright} 
     \@parboxrestore
     \if@minipage
       \@setminipage
     \fi
     \small
     \captiondelim{: }
     \@makecaption{\small 
     #1}{\ignorespaces \small 
     #2}\par
   \endgroup}



\AtEndPackage{caption}{
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{dash}{~\textendash ~}
    \DeclareCaptionFont{normalsize}{\normalsize}
      \captionsetup{
                    labelseparator=dash,
                    }
      \renewcommand{\configurecaptions}{%
                  \captionsetup{
                                singlelinecheck=false}}
      \renewcommand{\configureseparator}{\captionsetup{labelsep=colon}}
  }
}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setsecnumdepth{paragraph}
\settocdepth{paragraph}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\maxsecnumdepth{paragraph}

\newcommand{\subsubsubsection}{\paragraph}
\newcommand{\cftbeforesubsubsubsectionskip}{\cftbeforeparagraphskip}
\newcommand{\cftsubsubsubsectionfont}{\cftparagraphfont}
\newcommand{\setsubsubsubsecheadstyle}{\setparaheadstyle}

\setafterparaskip{1.0\onelineskip plus 0.5\onelineskip minus 0.2\onelineskip}
\setparaheadstyle{\normalfont\rmfamily\raggedright} 

%-------------------------------------------------------------------


\renewcommand{\cftfigurename}{\figurename\space} 
\renewcommand*{\cftfigureaftersnum}{\hfill \textendash \hfill} 
\renewcommand{\cftfigureafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip} 


\newcommand{\tipoilust}[1]{\renewcommand{\cftfigurename}{#1 \space}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{#1}
}

\newcommand{\ilustvaria}{
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{} 
}

\newcommand{\listilustvaria}{
\setlength{\cftfigurenumwidth}{24pt}
\setlength{\cftfigureindent}{0pt}
\begingroup
\renewcommand\numberline[1]{} 
\listoffigures*
\endgroup
}



\renewcommand{\cfttablename}{\tablename\space}
\renewcommand*{\cfttableaftersnum}{\hfill \textendash \hfill}   
\renewcommand{\cfttableafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip} 


\renewcommand{\tocheadstart}{\chapterfont}

\renewcommand*{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}

\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{0pt plus 0pt}
\renewcommand*{\insertchapterspace}{}

\cftinsertcode{A}{}

\newlength{\cftlastnumwidth}
\setlength{\cftlastnumwidth}{\cftsubsubsectionnumwidth+1em}

\newcommand{\tocprintchapter}{}
\newcommand{\tocinnonumchapter}{}
\newcommand{\tocprintchapternonum}{}
\newcommand{\tocpartapendices}{}
\newcommand{\tocpartanexos}{}

  \cftinsertcode{A}{\renewcommand{\cftchapteraftersnum}{\hfill \textendash \hfill}}

  \cftsetindents{part}{0em}{\cftlastnumwidth}
  \cftsetindents{chapter}{0em}{\cftlastnumwidth}
  \cftsetindents{section}{0em}{\cftlastnumwidth}
  \cftsetindents{subsection}{0em}{\cftlastnumwidth}
  \cftsetindents{subsubsection}{0em}{\cftlastnumwidth}
  \cftsetindents{paragraph}{0em}{\cftlastnumwidth}
  \cftsetindents{subparagraph}{0em}{\cftlastnumwidth}

  \renewcommand{\tocprintchapter}{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\cftsetindents{chapter}{0em}{\cftlastnumwidth}}}

  \renewcommand{\tocinnonumchapter}{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\cftsetindents{chapter}{\cftlastnumwidth}{2em}}%
    \cftinserthook{toc}{A}}

  \renewcommand{\tocprintchapternonum}{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\cftsetindents{chapter}{\cftlastnumwidth}{2em}}}

  \renewcommand{\tocpartapendices}{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\cftsetindents{part}{\cftlastnumwidth}{2em}}
    \cftinserthook{toc}{A}}

  \renewcommand{\tocpartanexos}{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\cftsetindents{part}{\cftlastnumwidth}{2em}}
    \cftinserthook{toc}{A}}


\newcommand{\phantompart}{%
  \bookmarksetup{startatroot}
  \phantomsection
}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------

\provideboolean{innonumchapter}  
\setboolean{innonumchapter}{true}
\makechapterstyle{abnt}{%
  \renewcommand{\chapterheadstart}{} 

  \ifx \chapternamenumlength \undefined
    \newlength{\chapternamenumlength}
  \fi

     \setlength{\beforechapskip}{0pt}
     \renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\chapterfont\chapterfontsize}
%%%   }

  \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\chaptitlefont}
  \renewcommand{\parttitlefont}{\partfont\partfontsize}
  \renewcommand{\partnumfont}{\partfont\partfontsize}
  \renewcommand{\partnamefont}{\partfont\partfontsize}


  \setsecheadstyle{\sectionfont\sectionfontsize
  }
  \setsubsecheadstyle{\subsectionfont\subsectionfontsize
  }
  \setsubsubsecheadstyle{\subsubsectionfont\subsubsectionfontsize
  }
  \setsubsubsubsecheadstyle{\subsubsubsectionfont\subsubsubsectionfontsize
  }

  \renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{}

  \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{%
   \chaptitlefont
   \ifthenelse{\boolean{apendiceousecao}}{\appendixname}{}%
  }

  \def\printchaptertitle##1{%
    \chaptitlefont%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{innonumchapter}}{\centering
    {##1}}{%
    % else  
      \ifthenelse{\boolean{apendiceousecao}}{\centering%
        \settowidth{\chapternamenumlength}{\printchaptername\printchapternum\afterchapternum}%
        {##1}%
      }{%
        \settowidth{\chapternamenumlength}{\printchaptername\printchapternum\afterchapternum}%
        \parbox[t]{\columnwidth-\chapternamenumlength}{%
        {##1}}}%
    }    
  }

  \renewcommand{\printchapternum}{%
     \tocprintchapter
     \setboolean{innonumchapter}{false}
     \bfseries %%
     \chapnumfont%
     \space\thechapter\space%
     \ifthenelse{\boolean{apendiceousecao}}{%
       \tocinnonumchapter
       \space--\space%
     }{} % 
  }
  \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}


  \renewcommand\printchapternonum{%
     \tocprintchapternonum
     \setboolean{innonumchapter}{true}%
    }
}
\chapterstyle{abnt}


\makepagestyle{abntchapfirst}
\makeoddhead{abntchapfirst}{}{}{\small\thepage}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\pretextual}{%
  \aliaspagestyle{chapter}{empty}
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \aliaspagestyle{cleared}{empty}
  \aliaspagestyle{part}{empty}
}
\renewcommand{\frontmatter}{\pretextual} 

\AtBeginDocument{\pretextual}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\titulo}[1]{\title{#1}}
\newcommand{\inseretitulo}{\thetitle}

\newcommand{\autor}[1]{\author{#1}}
\newcommand{\insereautor}{\theauthor}

\let\olddate\date
\renewcommand{\date}[1]{\AtBeginDocument{\olddate{#1}}}
\newcommand{\data}[1]{\date{#1}}
\newcommand{\inseredata}{\thedate}

\providecommand{\insereinstituicao}{}
\newcommand{\instituicao}[1]{\renewcommand{\insereinstituicao}{#1}}

\providecommand{\inserefaculdade}{}
\newcommand{\faculdade}[1]{\renewcommand{\inserefaculdade}{#1}}

\providecommand{\inserelocal}{}
\newcommand{\local}[1]{\renewcommand{\inserelocal}{#1}}

\providecommand{\inserenatureza}{}
\newcommand{\natureza}[1]{\renewcommand{\inserenatureza}{#1}}

\providecommand{\insereobjeto}{}
\newcommand{\objeto}[1]{\renewcommand{\insereobjeto}{#1}}

\providecommand{\insereprograma}{}
\newcommand{\programa}[1]{\renewcommand{\insereprograma}{#1}}

\providecommand{\inseresubtitulo}{}
\newcommand{\subtitulo}[1]{\renewcommand{\inseresubtitulo}{#1}}

\providecommand{\inserefinalcatalog}{}
\newcommand{\finalcatalog}[1]{\renewcommand{\inserefinalcatalog}{#1}}

\providecommand{\insereautorR}{}
\newcommand{\autorR}[1]{\renewcommand{\insereautorR}{#1}}

\providecommand{\insereorientadorOU}{}
\providecommand{\insereorientador}{}
\newcommand{\orientador}[2][\orientadorname]%
  {\renewcommand{\insereorientadorOU}{#1}%
   \renewcommand{\insereorientador}{#2}}

\providecommand{\inserecoorientadorOU}{}
\providecommand{\inserecoorientador}{}
\newcommand{\coorientador}[2][\coorientadorname]%
  {\renewcommand{\inserecoorientadorOU}{#1}%
   \renewcommand{\inserecoorientador}{#2}}

\providecommand{\insereorientadorTitulo}{}
\newcommand{\orientadorTitulo}[1]{\renewcommand{\insereorientadorTitulo}{#1}}

\providecommand{\inserecoorientadorTitulo}{}
\newcommand{\coorientadorTitulo}[1]{\renewcommand{\inserecoorientadorTitulo}{#1}}   


% ------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newenvironment{capa}{\begin{titlingpage}}{\end{titlingpage}\cleardoublepage}

\newcommand{\inserecapa}{%
  \begin{capa}%
   \begin{center}
    {\chapterfont \bfseries \MakeUppercase{\insereinstituicao} \par \MakeUppercase{\inserefaculdade} \par \MakeUppercase{\insereprograma}}
    \vfill
    {\chapterfont \bfseries \insereautor}
    \vfill
    \chapterfont{\bfseries \inseretitulo \mdseries \ifnotempty{\inseresubtitulo}{\textbf{:} \inseresubtitulo}}
    \vfill
    \inserelocal \par \inseredata 
   \end{center}
   \end{capa}
}

\newenvironment{folhaderosto}[1][\folhaderostoname]{\clearpage\AUbookmarkthis{#1}}{\newpage}%

%% --
\newcommand{\folhaderostocontent}{
  \begin{center}
    {\chapterfont \bfseries \insereautor} 
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begin{center}
      {\chapterfont \bfseries \inseretitulo \mdseries 
        \ifnotempty{\inseresubtitulo}{\textbf{:} \inseresubtitulo}}
    \end{center}
    \vspace*{\fill}
      \ifnotempty{\inserenatureza}{%
      \hspace{.45\textwidth}
      \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \SingleSpacing
         \inserenatureza
      \end{minipage}
       \vspace*{\fill}
    }
  \end{center} 
   {\insereorientadorOU ~\insereorientadorTitulo ~\insereorientador \par }
    \ifnotempty{\inserecoorientador}{%
       {\inserecoorientadorOU ~\inserecoorientadorTitulo ~\inserecoorientador}
    }
    \vfill
  \begin{center}  
    \inserelocal \par \inseredata   
  \end{center}
}
%% --

\newcommand{\inserefolhaderosto}[1]{%
  \begin{folhaderosto}{#1}
     \folhaderostocontent
  \end{folhaderosto}}


%% --
\newcommand{\inserecatalog}{
\thispagestyle{empty}

\ifthenelse{\boolean{@twoside}}
{}
{\addtocounter{page}{-1}}

{
\vspace*{15cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[c]{13cm}
\begin{center}
Ficha catalogr\'afica elaborada atrav\'es do Modelo Latex do CDC da UFJF com os dados fornecidos pelo(a) autor(a)
\end{center}
\end{minipage}

\fbox{\hspace*{0.3cm} \begin{minipage}[c]{12.5cm} \SingleSpacing \small
  \insereautorR . \par
  \hspace*{0.45cm} \inseretitulo \ifnotempty{\inseresubtitulo}{ : \inseresubtitulo} ~/ \insereautor. \textendash ~\inseredata .\par
  \hspace*{0.5cm} \pageref{LastPage} f. \if@eu@hasil : il.~\fi \\[12pt]
  \hspace*{0.45cm} \insereorientadorOU ~\insereorientador \par
    {\ifnotempty{\inserecoorientador}{%
       {\hspace*{0.45cm} \inserecoorientadorOU ~\inserecoorientador \par }%
    }
   }
  \hspace*{0.45cm} \insereobjeto ~\textendash ~\insereinstituicao , \inserefaculdade . \insereprograma , \inseredata . \\[12pt]
  \hspace*{0.5cm}  \inserefinalcatalog 
  \vspace*{12pt}
  \hspace*{0.3cm}
\end{minipage} \hspace*{0.3cm}}
\end{center}}
}


\newcommand{\inicfolhaaprov}{
\begin{center}
    {\chapterfont \bfseries \insereautor}

    \vfill
    \begin{center}
      {\chapterfont\bfseries\inseretitulo \mdseries \ifnotempty{\inseresubtitulo}{\textbf{:} \inseresubtitulo}}
    \end{center}
    \vfill

    \hspace{.45\textwidth}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \inserenatureza
    \end{minipage}%
    \vfill
   \end{center}
}

%%%


\newenvironment{folhadeaprovacao}[1][\folhadeaprovacaoname]{%
   \clearpage%
   \AUbookmarkthis{#1}%
   \begin{Spacing}{1.0}
}{\end{Spacing}%
\cleardoublepage}

\newenvironment{dedicatoria}[1][]{%
   \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{%
    \AUbookmarkthis{\dedicatorianame}
    }{\pretextualchapter{#1}}
    \vspace*{\fill} 
    \begin{quote}
    \addtolength{\leftskip}{4cm}
  }{%
    \end{quote}
  \cleardoublepage}

\newenvironment{agradecimentos}[1][\agradecimentosname]{%
   \pretextualchapter{#1}
  }{%
  \cleardoublepage}

\newenvironment{epigrafe}[1][]{%
   \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{%
    \AUbookmarkthis{\epigraphname}
    }{\pretextualchapter{#1}}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begin{quote}
    \addtolength{\leftskip}{4cm}
    }{%
  \end{quote}
  \cleardoublepage}

    \setlength\absleftindent{0cm}
    \setlength\absrightindent{0cm}
     \renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\normalsize}

\newenvironment{resumo}[1][\resumoname]{%
   \AUbookmarkthis{#1}
   \renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\chaptitlefont}
   \renewcommand{\abstractname}{\bfseries 
   {#1}}
   \begin{abstract}
  }{\end{abstract}%
\cleardoublepage}


\newenvironment{siglas}{%
  \pretextualchapter{\listadesiglasname}
  \begin{symbols} 
  \setlength{\itemsep}{-0.5em} 
  }{
  \end{symbols}
  \cleardoublepage
  }


\newenvironment{simbolos}{%
  \pretextualchapter{\listadesimbolosname}
\begin{symbols} 
\setlength{\itemsep}{-0.5em} 
}{%
\end{symbols}
  \cleardoublepage
}


\newenvironment*{citacao}[1][default]{%
   \list{}%
   \small%
   \addtolength{\leftskip}{4cm}%{\citacaorecuo}%
   \item[]%
   \begin{SingleSpace}%
   \ifthenelse{\not\equal{#1}{default}}{\itshape\selectlanguage{#1}}{}%
 }{%
   \end{SingleSpace}%
   \endlist}%

%% --
\newlist{alineas}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[alineas,1]{label={\alph*)},topsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,leftmargin=\parindent+\labelwidth-\labelsep}%
\newlist{subalineas}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[subalineas,1]{label={--},topsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,leftmargin=*}%
%% --

\newlength{\signwidth} 
\setlength{\signwidth}{10cm} 
\newlength{\signthickness} 
\setlength{\signthickness}{1pt}
\newlength{\signskip} 
\setlength{\signskip}{1cm} 

\newcommand{\assinatura}[1]{
  \begingroup\par\centering 
  \parbox[t]
  {\signwidth}{\SingleSpacing\vspace*{\signskip}\centering%
  \rule{\signwidth}{\signthickness}\\%
  \nopagebreak #1\par}
  \par\endgroup}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\textual}{%
    \pagestyle{simple} 
    \aliaspagestyle{chapter}{abntchapfirst}
  \nouppercaseheads%
  \bookmarksetup{startatroot}% 
\aliaspagestyle{cleared}{simple} 
  }
\renewcommand{\mainmatter}{\textual}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\postextual}{\phantompart}
\renewcommand{\backmatter}{\postextual}

%---

\newcommand*{\sistautordata}{\usepackage[authoryear, round]{natbib} 
\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}   
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\raggedright}  
}

\let\oldthebibliography=\thebibliography
\let\endoldthebibliography=\endthebibliography
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{\lineskip}
\renewcommand*{\biblistextra}{\raggedright}
\begin{oldthebibliography}{#1}%
\begin{SingleSpacing}
}%
{%
\end{SingleSpacing}
\end{oldthebibliography}%
}
%%---

\newcommand\@switch[1]{ \@writefile{toc}{\renewcommand*{\cftappendixname}{#1 \space}} }
\newcommand{\switchchapname}[1]{ \protected@write \@auxout {}{\string\@switch{#1} }}

\newcommand{\AUapendiceconfig}[2]{%
 \setboolean{apendiceousecao}{true}%
 \renewcommand{\appendixname}{#1}
 \renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{#2}
 \renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{#2}

 \switchchapname{#1}
 \renewcommand*{\cftappendixname}{#1 \space}
}

\newenvironment{apendicesenv}{%
 \AUapendiceconfig{\apendicename}{\apendicesname}
 \begin{appendix}
}{
 \end{appendix}
 \setboolean{apendiceousecao}{false}
 \bookmarksetup{startatroot}
}

\newenvironment{anexosenv}{%
 \cftinserthook{toc}{AAA}

 \AUapendiceconfig{\anexoname}{\anexosname}
 \begin{appendix}
 \renewcommand\theHchapter{anexochapback.\arabic{chapter}}
}{
 \end{appendix}
 \setboolean{apendiceousecao}{false}
 \bookmarksetup{startatroot}
}

% ---
```

**Edit**

The brackets are OK thanks the comment of Mico. I just would like to know how to get bold at the title of entries now. Using this style I get:

[image: Example]

I would like to get boldface on the title I've painted with yellow.

The `.bib` entry is:

```
@article{chapiro2016numerical,
  title={Numerical solution of a class of moving boundary problems with a nonlinear complementarity approach},
  author={Chapiro, Grigori and Gutierrez, Angel ER and Herskovits, Jos{\'e} and Mazorche, Sandro R and Pereira, Weslley S},
  journal={Journal of Optimization Theory and Applications},
  volume={168},
  number={2},
  pages={534--550},
  year={2016},
  publisher={Springer}
}
```

Comment: Please tell us whether you load a citation management package such as `cite` or `natbib`. And, if the answer is "yes", please do tell us with which options you load the package.

Comment: Hi, sir. Yes, I load `\usepackage{natbib}` and so, at postextual, `\bibliographystyle{abnt-num}
\bibliography{ref.bib}`. But I can change the package if necessary. I just like to get a simple and good ABNT-num style... I only cannot change the style of document, because this may be the original of University. Unfortunatelly, the original of University has not styles for .bib, once for beginner studients they preffer that the bibliography be written manually. I preffer .bib instead, because it's for a Master's work. Many thanks.

Comment: To get the numeric citation call-outs to be surrounded by square brackets instead of round parentheses, all you need to do is load the `natbib` package with the option `square`.

Comment: Many thanks! Brackets solved...

Comment: @Mico, please, did you also know as can I put boldface at the principal title of the items? Many thanks and sorry to bother.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by "principal title of the items". Are you referring to the header for the entire bibliography, i.e., something like "Bibliography" or "References"? Or are you maybe referring to the `title` field of entries of type `@article`, `@book`, etc? Please be specific.

Comment: @Mico, yes, I am referring to the title, for instance, on there we have bold at title: https://static.todamateria.com.br/upload/ab/nt/abnt3-0.jpg (Análise de textos de comunicação)... I am sorry for I did not be specific. The style I've posted is OK for my purposes, except for the bold that is missing. Thank you.

Comment: I still don't understand. The title of *what* is supposed to be bold?

Comment: @Mico, I am so sorry for the inconvenience. I've edited now the question and hope I've get to be understood. Many thanks and sorry. Maybe my hurry and poor English are troubles at my question. Thank you for attention.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't make sense of the code in `abnt-num.bst` and hence can't come with a suggestion for rendering the `title` field of bibliographic entries of type `@article` in **bold**. Sorry.

Comment: @Mico, OK, thank you so much for attention!

Comment: Please add an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) to your question. Otherwise, any solution will have to guess the specifics of how you are loading the relevant packages now and if that causes any conflicts.

Comment: @schtandard, please, could you take a look if this that I've edited is the expect for an MWE...? I am new here... Many thanks and sorry.

Comment: @Na'omi Well, it is neither very minimal nor complete. Maybe have a look at the link I provided for guidance on how to improve your example. For making titles bold, maybe have a look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10409/how-to-change-title-style-bibtex-bibliography). Other than that, I'm afraid I can't help you, I don't really know BibTeX. (By the way, BibTeX is outdated, nowadays `biblatex` is the way to go. If you can choose, maybe consider switching.)

Comment: Your class looks like a rehash of `abntex2`. as @schtandard said, there is a biblatex style called `biblatex-abnt` (the other `anbtex2-cite` package would help you with the brackets.) You can change the title of articles to bold with that more easily. Note, though, that for this may make sense, you'd have to change all titles (of books etc.) to bold, too. Besides, you **should not** do any of this if you wish to follow `ABNT` rules.

Comment: @Na'omi, would you accept a solution using `biblatex`? Besides, are you formatting your work according to UFJF's rules?

Comment: @schtandard, many thanks for the clues. I am sorry for the errors. Using `format.btitle` instead of `format.title` following the main ideia of the topic, I got italic on titles... This is strange. I need to learn more about biblatex, my attempt does not run... Thank you.

Comment: @Joseph, my attempt with `biblatex` does not run... I put `\usepackage[style=biblatex-abnt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}` in preambule and  `\printbibliography`, but the Bibliography does not appear... Sorry, I could not understand when you said "you should not do any of this if you wish to follow ABNT rules". Answering, yes, I follow UFJF's rules, but the style from UFJF has only bibitems.

Comment: @Na'omi, it's `\usepackage[style=abnt]{biblatex}`. Read the `biblatex-abnt` manual. "You should not do any of this if you wish to follow ABNT rules" because those rules are against what you want to do: see NBR 6023, "7.5.3 Artigo e/ou matéria de revista, boletim etc.". The logic is that an article is a part of a whole publication (just as in chapters of books). So it's just plain wrong to do this if you want to follow `ABNT` rules (and the UFJF exampe!), and you'd have to highlight article titles and journal titles differently.

Comment: It seems this class is a patchwork of code from `abntex2`, [ppgccufmg](https://github.com/wladston/master-thesis/blob/master/ppgccufmg.dtx), [this answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230343/caption-above-and-legend-below-environment-listings)...

Comment: @Joseph, all of your comments solved my problem. I'll accept the answer of hkh (once this solved the problem of boldface, even though this is wrong on optic of ANBT...), but would like to bounty you for solve my doubts. Could you post an abstract of your comments as an answer? Many thanks. Saudações.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the right tools: I think you should take a look on [Bibulous](http://nzhagen.github.io/bibulous/)

> a drop-in replacement for BibTeX that makes use of style templates instead of BibTeX’s BST language.

It is based on templates, and it is developed to solve such a problem.

> Bibulous developed out of frustration with the complexity of creating bibliography styles using BibTeX’s obscure language, ...

Take a look on the examples on their page.

EDIT: here is a MWE using `bibulous` to achieve what the OP needs.

`mwe.tex` :

```
\documentclass [11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\nocite{chapiro2016numerical}
\bibliographystyle{mystyle}
\bibliography{./mybib}
\end{document}
```

`mybib.bib` :

```
@article{chapiro2016numerical,
  title={Numerical solution of a class of moving boundary problems with a nonlinear complementarity approach},
  author={Chapiro, Grigori and Gutierrez, Angel ER and Herskovits, Jos{\'e} and Mazorche, Sandro R and Pereira, Weslley S},
  journal={Journal of Optimization Theory and Applications},
  volume={168},
  number={2},
  pages={534--550},
  year={2016},
  publisher={Springer}
}
```

`mystyle.bst`:

```
TEMPLATES:
article = \uppercase{<au>} \textbf{<title>}. \textit{<journal>},<publisher>, v. <volume>, n. <number>, p. <pages>, <year>.

OPTIONS:
maxauthors = 1 
namelist_format = last_name_first
etal_message =  \lowercase{ et al.}
```

this file is the one you should create and customize (follow [bibliography style templates](http://nzhagen.github.io/bibulous/guidelines_for_writing_style_templates.html)). I this example I used the `.bib` provided by OP. For real case the template should include rules for books, proceeding, ...

my working folder tree is:

```
.
├── main.tex
├── mybib.bib
└── mystyle.bst
```

Download `bibulous.py`, make it executable (`chmod +x bibulous`), then invoke the following commands in the working directory:

```
 pdflatex main.tex            # this will creat .aux file
 /path/to/bibulous.py main.aux
 pdflatex main.tex
```

Of course, you need a working python 3 installation.

Here is the result:
[image]

Hoping that would help.

EDIT2: uppercase author name, lastname first

Comment: This reads more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: should I add a MWE ?

Comment: An MWE would be helpful if it tells the OP how he/she may solve the relevant formatting issues.

Comment: @hkh, many thanks for your interesting answer! I'll just wait the commentator that said that I should not done somethings following the ABNT rules, so if there's not a way automatic with ABNT I'll learn more about Bibulous. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that the class you're using is a patchwork of code copied from `abntex2` without acknowledgement and further complicated, [ppgccufmg](https://github.com/wladston/master-thesis/blob/master/ppgccufmg.dtx), this answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230343/caption-above-and-legend-below-environment-listings) and maybe more, so weird things may occur along the way (or not). Besides, it doesn't even use `bibtex`, not to mention `biblatex`, for bibliography management.

Another caveat: you should **not** do any of this (i.e., change the bibliography format) if you wish to follow ABNT rules because those rules are against what you want to do: see NBR 6023, "7.5.3 Artigo e/ou matéria de revista, boletim etc.". The logic is that an article is a part of a whole publication (just as in chapters of books). So it's just plain wrong to do this if you want to follow ABNT rules (and the UFJF exampe), and you'd have to highlight article titles and journal titles differently (as in **bold** vs. *italics*).

And now the full answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{article,
    journaltitle = {The Journal},
    pages = {22-24},
    title = {The title},
    volume = {5},
    year = {2005},
    author={John Doe}}    

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=abnt-numeric,ittitles]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib} % if you’re using biblatex

\DeclareFieldFormat
[article]
{title}{\textbf{#1}}


%%%%%if you want brackets in text and bibliography%%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cites}[\mkbibbrackets]{\cite}{\multicitedelim}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\parencites}[\mkbibbrackets]{\parencite}{\multicitedelim}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{Disponível em:\addcolon\addspace\url{#1}
}%



\begin{document}

\cite{article}.


\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.